# Converter um to_date sql para um date java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Meu problema é o seguinte, eu tenho que pegar linhas de insert SQL e verificar se os formatos na função TO_DATE nesses inserts são válidos com um método java. Para um formato 'DD/MM/YYYY' o SimpleDateFormat resolve meu problema, mas às vezes é necessário um insert no formato 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' e ai o SimpleDateFormat não aceita esse formato, como posso ver isso? Segue o código do meu método Java.

```
boolean retorno = true;
    try {
        if (line.matches(".*TO_DATE.*")) {
            String[] linha_quebrada = line.split("TO_DATE");
            ArrayList<String> datas = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < linha_quebrada.length; i++) {
                if (linha_quebrada[i].substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("(")) {
                    datas.add(linha_quebrada[i]);
                }
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < datas.size(); k++) {
                String toDate = null;
                int inicio;
                int fim;
                if (datas.get(k).substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("(")) {
                    toDate = datas.get(k).substring(0, datas.get(k).length() - 1);
                    inicio = toDate.indexOf("(") + 1;
                    fim = toDate.indexOf(")");
                    toDate = toDate.substring(inicio, fim);
                    String[] data_formato = toDate.split(",");
                    String data = data_formato[0].replace("'", "");
                    String formato = data_formato[1].replace("'", "").trim();
                    /*java.sql.Date dateSQL = new Date*/
                    SimpleDateFormat formatoData = new SimpleDateFormat(formato);
                    Date dataJava = formatoData.parse(data);
                    System.out.println(dataJava.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        retorno = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que esse formato 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' não é compatível com o SimpleDateFormat, tem que ser um que seja. Por exemplo:

'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' > 01/05/2014 23:10:55

'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' > 01/05/2014 11:10:55

Um desses vai resolver seu problema.

Comment: Senti falta desse link na resposta: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Resolve, mas queria saber uma forma deu verificar todos os tipos de máscaras que existem no SQL, será que tem uma forma de colocar todos eles de forma que eu possa validar nesse método que eu criei?